# Aligning content vertically

Tags: html, css, alignment

Not sure how to ask this question. Basically, I'm trying to add YouTube videos to my page and have a  element next to it with a blurb about the video. I'm going to add 4 videos and 4 blurbs total. When I went to add the next video using , the video wasn't placed under the first one. I went to add another  property and it wouldn't show up. Can anyone help me figure out how to vertically align videos on top of each other then place the  elements next to each video, also aligning them on top?

My HTML:

```
<div class="boonie">
</div>
<div class="blaze">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.boonie {
position: absolute;
background-color:#FA8440;
right: 5px;
width: 600px;
height: 290px;
border: 6px solid #4d4d4d;
padding: 5px;
left: 440px;}

.blaze {
position: absolute;
background-color:#FA8440;
right: 5px;
width: 600px;
height: 290px;
border: 6px solid #4d4d4d;
padding: 5px;
left: 440px;}
```

Comment: I meant to say <div> element.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're aiming for? Just a picture or something would be fine.

Comment: Have you done a search for this? Vertically aligning content is a very commonly asked question.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5vPL4.png..I want what I have in the photo to be duplicated vertically. I want another video placed on the next line and a div with a blurb next to the video, just like I have it in the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position from absolute to relative for each class:

```
.boonie {
position: relative;
background-color:#FA8440;
right: 5px;
width: 600px;
height: 290px;
border: 6px solid #4d4d4d;
padding: 5px;
left: 440px;}

.blaze {
 position: relative;
background-color:#FA8440;
right: 5px;
width: 600px;
height: 290px;
border: 6px solid #4d4d4d;
padding: 5px;
left: 440px;}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5yrm03b/)

Comment: When I make the second one relative, it moves the text over. Another issue I'm running into is that the videos and div elements are stacking on top of each other instead of below, like on the next line. Here's my code:

Comment: <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5wi7zfAlsM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen align="left"></iframe>
</iframe>
<div class="boonie">
<h2>Boonie Mayfield</h2>
<p> </p>
</div>
<div class="blaze">
<h2>Just Blaze</h2>
<p> </p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve?
(Adjust dimensions...)

```css
.row{
  width:1080px;
  height:315px;
  margin:10px auto;
}
.video{
  float:left;
  width:420px;
}
.video iframe {
  display:block;
  width:420px;
  height:315px;
  border:0;
}
.description{
  float:left;
  background:orange;
  border:5px solid #303030;
  margin-left:60px;
  width:600px;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/U5wi7zfAlsM"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Boonie</h2>
    <p>Boonie description here...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/U5wi7zfAlsM"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
  <h2>Blaze</h2>
  <p>Blaze description here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5vPL4.png...basically I want what I have in the photo. I want to add another video, another blurb in a div next to the video and so forth.

Comment: See edited snippet. Pretty much the desired layout, isn't it?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but when I insert the video the formatting looks off. What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, the video is a youtube video, so I'm using the iframe link to embed it